# IntelliJ IDEA GitLab integration

Tags: intellij-idea, gitlab, intellij-plugin

Does InteliJ IDEA has GitLab integration? I couldn't find any Merge Requests and Code Review management. May be some plugins are needed? Could you advice?

Answer (score 8):

GitLab integration is in the progress of active development, please see and follow [IDEA-109294](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109294).

There are a few 3rd-party plugins that implement GitLab functionality:

- [GitLab Merge Requests](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18689-gitlab-merge-requests).
- [Merge Request Integration CE - Code Review for GitLab](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13607-merge-request-integration-ce--code-review-for-gitlab).
- [GitLab Projects 2020](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14110-gitlab-projects-2020/).

Answer (score 1):

For its Code Completion, GitLab has released an [official Plugin](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/editor-extensions/gitlab-jetbrains-plugin), it is currently in Beta.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to review GitLab merge requests in IntelliJ. However, at the moment, you cannot create them. To address this, I developed a plugin, allowing you to quickly create merge requests, assign reviewers, and more: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/22799-gitlab-merge-request

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11149-gitlab-quick-merge-request is another plugin claiming to allow MR creation as well. You may also want to remove the `"` from your URL - it breaks the link.